# how do u get an associated file type to open up within the application itself after being converted from python to exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to have my program's associated file types open up directly into my Text Editor created using python's as well as incorporate a drag-and-drop functionality into the core of my program. How would i do this?

Also when trying to open up the associated file type directly using the `file.ext` link it just opens up a blank screen of my application window. How do i fix this?

I am using `Python 2.7.12` for programming and `PyInstaller` for converting to `exe`

The files are already associated to my Text Editor via `Inno Setup Compiler` however I would like them to actually open up properly within the Text Editor itself.

Comment: I think you can set defaults by right-clicking and choosing "Open With..", the other half of your question, I'm not even sure.. how are you converting python to an executable?

Comment: @mangoHero1 I am using PyInstaller to convert Python to an Executable

Answer (score 0):

Your program needs to accept parameters, the parameter in this case is going to be the file that will open with the editor that you created.

Drag and drop depends on the GUI framework that you are using. Google the framework that you are using and add "Drag and drop". There is definitely a documentation on how to implement it in the desired framework.

File association usually is done via installers such as the NSIS installer [NSIS installer file association](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/File_Association)